# How work with degree or start and stop in linear-gradient CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to duplicate this button in CSS3: [image: Orange button]

this is mu CSS code:

```
#banneroverlaping > a:link, #banneroverlaping > a:visited{
color: white;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
background: #FA733B;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #FA733B 0%, #FA733B 50%, #FF501C 51%, #FF501C 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#FA733B), color-stop(50%,#FA733B), color-stop(51%,#FF501C), color-stop(100%,#FF501C));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #FA733B 0%, #FA733B 50%,#FF501C 51%,#FF501C 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #FA733B 0%, #FA733B 50%,#FF501C 51%,#FF501C 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #FA733B 0%, #FA733B 50%,#FF501C 51%,#FF501C 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #FA733B 0%, #FA733B 50%,#FF501C 51%,#FF501C 100%);
}
```

so I get this:

[image: Orange button 2]

as you can see the cut between the two colors doesn't start at the corners  but rather in the center. So my question is how may I code it to duplicate the original image???

thanks in advance

I base my code using [this site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a white right triangle with the same height and width of the button, alpha level of 70% and place it as background image

```
background: url(file:///home/juanpa/Public/a/img/Ontario.png) left no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

this gradient works for a square box:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(4% 0%, rgb(62,203,103) 48%, rgb(93,244,134) 57%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    4% 0%,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.48, rgb(62,203,103)),
    color-stop(0.57, rgb(93,244,134))
);
```

now `xStart is 4% and yStart=0%`
you can change xStart to move the gradient anti-clockwise.
the 0.48 or 48% is the color on the top (in this css the deep green) and 57% is the light green. you can adjust that accordingly....
if the ratio of the color-stops are 1, i.e. 57% and 57% for example, then you will have a line seperating the two gradients. and if its not, depending on which one is larger, it will try to blend into the one with lower value